# Reorder an array from a specific data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, filter

I have absolutely no idea of which title I could write.
Actually, here is what I get from API :

```
[
    {
      "order": 1,
      "role": {
        "label": "singer"
      },
      "artist": {
        "name": "AaRON"
      }
    },
    {
      "order": 1,
      "role": {
        "label": "author"
      },
      "artist": {
        "name": "Simon Buret"
      }
    },
    {
      "order": 2,
      "role": {
        "label": "author"
      },
      "artist": {
        "name": "Olivier Coursier"
      }
    },
    {
      "order": 1,
      "role": {
        "label": "composer"
      },
      "artist": {
        "name": "John Doe"
      }
    }
  ]
```

And here is what I need to send :

```
"artist": {
  "singer": [
    "AaRON"
  ],
  "author": [
     "Simon Buret",
     "Olivier Coursier"
  ]
}
```

Of course, the order property must be taken in account.

Example : Simon Buret is the first item because he has the order set to 1.

I have absolutely no idea how to implement that, I just did a map, but don't know what to put inside :/

```
this.artistControl.controls.map(artistControl => {
   ...
});
```

Is there a way to do what I need ?

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. You might also explain why the blank composer also with `"order": 1` was left out (I'm guessing because the name is blank, but...).

Comment: Any reason you’re leaving out the composer?

Comment: The composer is empty because of the poor API I'm working with ... I will update my post and fill this property because it seems to disturb you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```js
let arr = [
    { "order": 1, "role": { "label": "singer" }, "artist": { "name": "AaRON" } },
    { "order": 1, "role": { "label": "author" }, "artist": { "name": "Simon Buret" } },
    { "order": 2, "role": { "label": "author" }, "artist": { "name": "Olivier Coursier" } },
    { "order": 1, "role": { "label": "composer" }, "artist": { "name": "John Doe" } }
];

let obj = {'artist': {}};
arr.forEach(a => {
    obj['artist'][a.role.label] = obj['artist'][a.role.label] || [];
    obj['artist'][a.role.label][a.order-1] = a.artist.name;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Yeah I think it could work ! Some of my values are in 'disable' mode, because they are form values but I can adapt what you've done I think ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method with object as a accumulator param and then check if the key doesn't exist create it with empty array as value and then add names by order.

```js
const data = [{"order":1,"role":{"label":"singer"},"artist":{"name":"AaRON"}},{"order":1,"role":{"label":"author"},"artist":{"name":"Simon Buret"}},{"order":2,"role":{"label":"author"},"artist":{"name":"Olivier Coursier"}},{"order":1,"role":{"label":"composer"},"artist":{"name":"John Doe"}}]

const result = data.reduce((r, {
  role: { label },
  artist: { name },
  order
}) => {
  if (name) {
    if (!r[label]) r[label] = [];
    r[label][order - 1] = name;
  }
  
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your solution is more complex to me. But I implement it and it's working too. Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [{"order":1,"role":{"label":"singer"},"artist":{"name":"AaRON"}},{"order":1,"role":{"label":"author"},"artist":{"name":"Simon Buret"}},{"order":2,"role":{"label":"author"},"artist":{"name":"Olivier Coursier"}},{"order":1,"role":{"label":"composer"},"artist":{"name":"John Doe"}}];

const result = array
  .sort((item1, item2) => item1.order - item2.order)
  .reduce((acc, { role, artist }) => ({
    ...acc,
    artist: {
      ...acc.artist,
      [role.label]: [
        ...(acc.artist[role.label] || []),
        artist.name,
      ],
    },
  }), { artist: {} });
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach with es5

```js
const data = [{ "order": 1, "role": { "label": "singer" }, "artist": { "name": "AaRON" } }, { "order": 1, "role": { "label": "author" }, "artist": { "name": "Simon Buret" } }, { "order": 2, "role": { "label": "author" }, "artist": { "name": "Olivier Coursier" } }, { "order": 1, "role": { "label": "composer" }, "artist": { "name": "John Doe" } }];

 var result = data.reduce(function(map, obj) {
            map["artist"] = map["artist"] || {};
            if (obj.role.label === 'author' || obj.role.label === 'singer') {
                map["artist"][obj.role.label] = map["artist"][obj.role.label] || [];
                map["artist"][obj.role.label][obj.order - 1] = obj.artist.name;
            }
            return map;
 }, {});
        
 console.log(result)
```